# HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument is not loading html in Sitecore Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing powershell script that reads HTML from rich text field and then updates it. I am trying to use HtmlAgilityPack to read html.

To test HtmlAgilityPack I wrote short script (below), which runs successfully (loads html and prints it to screen) in Powershell ISE, but does not load html when run in Sitecore powershell editor.

Any ideas what I am missing?

```
$html = "<p>Testing</p>"
Add-Type -path "C:\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlAgilityPack.dll"
$doc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$doc.LoadHtml($html)
Write-Host "Text:" $doc.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$html = "<p>Testing</p>"
$doc = New-Object -TypeName HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$doc.LoadHtml($html)
Write-Host "Text:" $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p")[0].InnerHtml
```

-Hetal